# installing only one target in cmake

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules, cmake-language

I have totally 5 targets. one of them is static library. other 4 are executables.
I don't want the library to be build for every time. so i just want to compile the library keep it in a particular location so that other executables can refer this library. i understood that we can do this by using `install` command.

But if i use `install` command, it is compiling all the targets. how to only compile one target and intall it into a location ?

```
add_compile_definitions(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY true)
install(TARGETS mylib DESTINATION lib)
```

Comment: not really clear what you are trying to achieve: if you want to make your library extrenal to your project, installing it won't be enough as the insternal deps remains on the local build.

Answer (score 0):

it works by changing the command as below

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY true)
install(TARGETS mylib DESTINATION lib)
```